# Site won't adjust to mobile width/meta tag?

Tags: html, css, mobile, width

"I'm new to coding and I'm having trouble resizing my site for mobile devices. The website works okay for desktop, and everything's set except somehow it won't detect the device-width when on mobile, so the site stretches all the way, and I'd have to move around with the scrollbars."

This question has been answered! And if you've had a similar problem,

have a media query:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css"/>
```

and already tried:

- checking if adding user-scalable or maximum scale would make any
  difference
- adding a set width or height to the html and body tag
- deleting the margins
- floating everything to the left
- deleting overflow
- deleting the reset
- experimenting with min and max widths
- using vh instead of %

There is an answer below!

Also here is a [tutorial](http://www.elementfusion.com/tutorial-optimizing-your-website-for-mobile-devices) for mobile optimization that I used as reference.

Comment: What happens if you add `user-scalable=no` to your viewport meta content? (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`)

Comment: And I'd lose the conditions for your style sheet. Try removing the media attribute there all together. If you need rules for a specific screen size, use the media query in css http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I'm not able to zoom out but the site still isn't fit to the width;;

and yeah ! someone pointed the media attribute out to me too -- I'll edit the post

Comment: So you want the whole site to adjust to the screen width for larger screens, too?

Comment: Nope, just for mobile.

Comment: Your body still has a `min-width`:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<body>` still has a `min-width` which is keeping it from shrinking down to screen size.

I added some rules to make it fit:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

body{
min-width: 0;   /* let the body shrink */
}

#copyright{
margin-left: 0px;
}

#ladder{
width: 100%;   /* have the screen dictate the image size */
height: auto;
margin-left: 0;
padding: 10px;    /* still use padding... */
box-sizing: border-box;   /* ...but make it go on the inside */
}

}
```

Comment: Added missing parenthesis in media query

Comment: Adding a min-width worked! I see now-- thank you for that, and for making other fixes too!! will adjust accordingly =)

Comment: Well, actually we *removed* the `min-width`. There was one before (1280px; in style.css, line 49), and we removed the restriction by setting it to 0. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You said you used `vh` to scale for it and it didn't work. I'm not sure why that happened (I'm assuming it's because the height of a website always changes depending on the amount of content in it). I think a better solution would just be to use `vw` or "viewport width". It's a good solution and it works great on the website I'm working on. **Note:** Might not work if there's a horizontal scrollbar.
Just find the width of your device in pixels. Try:

```
console.log(window.outerWidth)
```

Then, simply convert all `px` on the page to `vw` using the equation below that converts x pixels to this unit:

```
x * (100vw/window.outerWidth)
```

**Note 2:** This is not what you put in the code. Just use the equation, crunch the numbers on a calaculator, and replace all units on that page to `vw`.

Anyway, hopefully this helped!